# How do I use a variable in FormulaR1C1?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formula to get the closest value to given value i.e.,

```
=SMALL(R1C1:R1C144,COUNTIF(R1C1:R1C144,""<"" &8)+1 )
```

will give the closest value to 8.

I want to use variable instead of direct number "(8)"

Please help me. This is my current code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
Dim col As Integer 
col = Me.TextBox1.Value
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SMALL($A$1:$EN$1,COUNTIF($A$1:$EN$1," < "&col)+1)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you've tagged your question with VBA, Is there some code you have? Where is the variable coming from?

Comment: Hello Tim,
 Thank you for reply
 Here is my code
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() Dim col As Integer col = Me.TextBox1.Value ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SMALL($A$1:$EN$1,COUNTIF($A$1:$EN$1," < "&col)+1)" End Sub Private Sub TextBox1_Change() End Sub

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
Dim col As Integer 
col = Me.TextBox1.Value
 'EDIT: .FormulaR1C1 should be .Formula   
ActiveCell.Formula = "=SMALL($A$1:$EN$1,COUNTIF($A$1:$EN$1,""<" & col & """)+1)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Tim ,
Thank you for your time But unfortunately I am getting runtime error 1004

Comment: Hello Tim , Can You please teach me how to deal with this one I am getting error called Runtime error 1004

Comment: Can You please teach me how to deal with this one I am getting error called Runtime error 1004

Comment: I think you got the answer to this in a different question: use `Formula` and not `FormulaR1C1`.  I edited my response to show that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to do this in excel seperate from VBA then you don't really need a variable. You should just put any value you want in a separate cell (in this example cell A5) and then reference that cell in you formula like this:

```
=SMALL(R1C1:R1C144,COUNTIF(R1C1:R1C144,""<"" & A5)+1 )
```

I don't believe you'd want a VBA solution since your algorithm so far is all in Excel syntax. However if you did want to do it in VBA you'd need to find the algorithm in VBA syntax and declare a variable like this:

```
Dim myNumber As Integer

myNumber = 5          'put whatever number you want here
```